# How to config gnome-shell to run on GPU instead CPU?

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, gnome-shell, performance, process

This week I formatted my laptop and installed the new Ubuntu 22.04 (I was using 20.04), and after switching the OS, I found it slower than it was in 20.04 and I also, I found a lot of problems in this new version;

I had a problem with the brightness of my second monitor and was doing some investigation so I did note that my gnome-shell is not using my GPU but CPU to run, and I think that this can be the reason for the performance issue.

GPU processes:
[image]

CPU processes:
[image]

A few info about my machine:
[image]

So, I would like to understand why it happens and how to fix it.

Regards,
Leonardo

Comment: Hey @Quasímodo I do not have a so depth knowledge about the OS... It's only a hypothesis about the problem I have, as when I had the gnome-shell running on GPU it was running faster, so I need to test and validate if it is or not my problem; So, I would be grateful if you can help with all your wisdom

Comment: Hey @Quasímodo, thanks for your answer... I'm not sure, but I think that the problem was solved by `sudo prime-select nvidia`... I do not remember if it was enabled on my config in the 20.04 or if I was using on-demand, but now the gnome-shell and some other applications are running on the GPU